# Download file on Push Notification Android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

I'm trying to open an `Activity` and download a file via `HttpPost` after clicking on push `notification`. I'm new to `Android Programming`. I'm not sure where I should be putting the code for downloading a file via `HttpPost` below?

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyGcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
}
}
```

My Intent Service class:

```
    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
    public static final String TAG="TEST";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Bundle extras;
     public GcmIntentService()
        {
            super("GcmIntentService");
        }

     @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         extras = intent.getExtras();
         GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
         String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);


         if (!extras.isEmpty()) { 

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                 sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
             } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    sendNotification(extras.toString());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }


         }
         MyGcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
     }

         private void sendNotification(String msg) {
                mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MainPage.class), 0);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New Message")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(extras.getString("Message:").substring(extras.getString("Message:").indexOf(":")+2, extras.getString("Message:").length())))
                .setContentText(extras.toString().substring((extras.toString().indexOf("="))+1, extras.toString().indexOf("_")));

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            }


}
```

Comment: As i can see you already starting a new activity on notification click, now what exactly you want,????

Comment: You want code to download file which you will put in **MainPage.class** ???

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for replying. I have already written code to go to another activity  called 'MainPage' when clicking on Notification. But what I want is where to put the code to download an image via HttpPost and show when it reaches the 'MainPage' activity?

Comment: I figured it out by Myself

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to show pushnotification and just download the image on Push notification.

There are few libraries for same. You can use Event bus and get Event of pushnotification received in your activity. Than after you can download image in main Activity.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

In same way you can show Notification as well and send event to MainActivity for download Image and show it.